# Why doesn't Loader sets parent's width and height?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Why, when I load a component with `Loader`, the `width` and `height` aren't copied form parent item ?

This code should show a red rectangle but it doesn't:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Pane {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Loader {
            sourceComponent: redsq
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: redsq
        Rectangle {
            //width: 100;
            //height: 40;
            anchors.fill:  parent
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I uncomment the `width` and `height` and comment the `anchors` part, it will work fine:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100;
    height: 40;
    //anchors.fill:  parent
    color: "red"
}
```

Output of `bin/qmlscene`:

[image: Loader works correctly]

So , what is the problem here, isn't it supposed that properties are propagating by `property binding` system? Or does `Loader` miss some features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader is not being filled by the content by default, nor does it assume the content's size by default.

You can either bind the loader size to the content item size, or bind the content item size to the loader size.

Currently, your loader has zero width and height. So any items filling it will have zero size as well. Have another `anchors.fill: parent` for the loader, or just replace the `Item` with the `Loader` as the former is redundant.

Comment: _The loader is not being filled by the content by default, nor does it assume the content's size by default._  That's not entirely true : [loader sizing behavior](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loader-sizing-behavior). For anchors to work, they have to be on the loader though.